# How to get auto increment id by PDO before execute

Tags: php, sql

I looking for an solutions on 'How to get auto increment id by PDO before execute', is there a way to get the future ID in pdo.

I tried lastinsertID but that can only after the 'execute'.

Below you find the original:

```
$last_id = $dbh->lastInsertId(); //last insert ID
```

My PDO Query

```
$insert = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO _gegevensgebruiker (id, company, name, adress, zipcode, city, tel, email, employees, representative, email_re, function, date_end, user, `date_add`) VALUES (NULL, :company, :name, :adress, :zipcode, :city, :tel, :email, :employees, :representative, :email_re, :function, :date_end, :meid, NOW())');
```

I know the way to get the last_id but i need a solution to get an future id inside the PDO statement.

Below my instert_ID solution outside the PDO statement:

```
$lastusers_sql = $dbh->prepare('SELECT MAX(id) FROM users');
$lastusers_sql->execute();
$last_id = $lastusers_sql->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: before inserting anything, why don't you get MAX(your_id_field) from your database? lastisertid will give you id that was just created, after creation. To that MAX(your_id_field), you add +1, and you get your next id, if somebody doesn't do insert in between )) why would you need this functionality?

Comment: If you read my question you'll see that i need the future id inside the pdo statement. So i don't understand you -1, because everybody knows the solutions of lastID after execute, but my question is about a future id inside the statement. So do you have a solutions for future ID ?

Comment: i didn't give you -1 mate. Joshua just answered with MAX(id)+1

Comment: Obviously futureID must be MAX(ID)+1 if is autoincremental. Otherwhise this shall be done outside DB via external script who takes care about this ID.

Comment: $insert = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO _gegevensgebruiker ((SELECT MAX(id)+1), company, name, adress, zipcode, city, tel, email, employees, representative, email_re, function, date_end, user, `date_add`) VALUES (NULL, :company, :name, :adress, :zipcode, :city, :tel, :email, :employees, :representative, :email_re, :function, :date_end, :meid, NOW())');
 
instead of id, insert "(SELECT MAX(id)+1)" which gives your next id, is this what you want? i dont' get it. But again it doesn't make much sence because your ID will be already MAX(id)+1

Comment: @MuhammedM. Thnx!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Accept my answer, Vote up on my comments, if u like ))

Comment: @MuhammedM. I've vote it :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$insert = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO _gegevensgebruiker ((SELECT MAX(id)+1), company, name, adress, zipcode, city, tel, email, employees, representative, email_re, function, date_end, user, `date_add`) VALUES (NULL, :company, :name, :adress, :zipcode, :city, :tel, :email, :employees, :representative, :email_re, :function, :date_end, :meid, NOW())');
```

Comment: instead of id, insert "(SELECT MAX(id)+1)" which gives your next id, is this what you want? i dont' get it. But again it doesn't make much sence because your ID will be already MAX(id)+1.

Answer (score 1):

You can do INSERT with SELECT MAX():

```
INSERT INTO table1 
(id, column1, column2) 
(SELECT (MAX(id)+1), 'value1', 'value2' FROM table1)
```

and increment ID column with whatever you want value.

Answer (score -1):

Create a UID.

```
$uid = '123#!';
// $dbh->execute();
$lastId = $uid;
```

Don't set your id column on autoincr. else it doesn't work.