# PDO insert max id+1 not auto_increment

Tags: mysql, pdo, insert, auto-increment

I don't want to use auto increment of mysql ,But I want to get max id+1 to insert as ID for next data.

I tried to do as [How to get auto increment id by PDO before execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35698529/how-to-get-auto-increment-id-by-pdo-before-execute/)
But no luck.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO checklist ((SELECT MAX(checklist_id)+1), checklist_name ) VALUES (NULL, :checklist_name)";

$pdo_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare( $sql );

$result = $pdo_statement->execute ((array(':maxid'=>NULL,':checklist_name'=>$_POST['checklist_name']));
```

Could you please help me what code it should be?

Comment: This is dangerous you know. What if two INSERT's hit simultaneously? You will then get the same result from your "SELECT MAX(.....)" and the two INSERT statements will then try to insert the same ID, thus causing an error on one of them. Why don't you want to use auto-incremment? What is your use case?

Comment: Some MySQL's features will be optimized better if you use a `AUTO_INCREMENT` column (in combination with a `PRIMARY KEY` OR `UNIQUE` key) within your table and the difference is (very) noticable when using InnoDB as table engine ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html )... In fact every InnoDB table should have a PRIMARY or UNIQUE key to gain better performance i once post a answer about it (let me see if i can still find it)

Comment: " In fact every InnoDB table should have a PRIMARY or UNIQUE key to gain better performance i once post a answer about it (let me see if i can still find it) " Found it https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48072/why-does-mysql-ignore-the-index-even-on-force-for-this-order-by/48184#48184

Comment: _I don't want to use auto increment of mysql_ - But why? Not only is it more convenient, but it's safer too.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: as one of the commentors have pointed out above; it is not recommended to not have PRIMARY Key in your MySQL Database*

Your SQL query is wrong. You need to have columns and values separately.

> $sql = "INSERT INTO checklist ((SELECT MAX(checklist_id)+1), checklist_name ) VALUES (NULL, :checklist_name)";

To make your INSERT statement correct look at the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html)

```
INSERT INTO table (column, column, etc.) VALUES (value, value, etc.)
```

So to make your statement correct you will have to switch some of the variables

```
INSERT INTO checklist (checklist_id, checklist_name) VALUES ((SELECT MAX(checklist_id)+1 FROM checklist), :checklist_name)
```

And your array with your bind values will look like this

```
array(':checklist_name' => $_POST['checklist_name'])
```

If you have problems with any SQL syntax you can look at the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) or [w3schools tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp).

Comment: @mrunion said in the comments that this is a very **unsafe** method because of **race conditions**